# What are the reasons to have strong password at home?

Tags: password, security

For a typical home PC the security situation is following:

- No servers running, not even the SSH. Firewall is `ufw` running in simple mode: all outgoing allowed, all incoming denied. Torrents and DC++ may be. May often be behind a router without port forwarding.
- All sensitive or valuable information already available for read and write for the user and resides in his `/home`
- Physical presence of attacker is impossible. (by impossible I mean that if attacker is present near PC, the PC is a least concern in situation).
- Being a specific target of skilled attacker is astronomically improbable.
- DE with autologin enabled.

**Question:** In the situation described, what vectors of attack there are, in which the strength of user password is relevant? Can, for example, a malicious web site has a chance to attempt bruteforcing? If, for example, user runs a malicious script, would it not be much easier for it to put itself in autorun and wait for user to use `sudo` than do bruteforcing? Why would it need root at all - all fun things are already available?

I want to make a weighted decision about the password length. I am actively converting people to Linux and typing passwords scares them.  Typing secure password a lot annoys me too. It is just stupid to have a password when nobody will ever try to force it or steal hash.

Comment: Please, before marking this question as duplicate, try to find an answer that does not contradict one of the obvious terms above.

Comment: I want to decide what sort of passwords to set for new users: will "123" be enough, or should I do at least something non-dictionary (and thus, prone to forgetting and mistyping).

Comment: @BarafuAlbino it can be. If there is a slim chance of someone else getting onto the machine it'll be fine. An average user might benefit from automatic login. I hardly need my sudo password as is myself. My 70-year old mother has an Ubuntu machine since 1/2 a year (no prior computer knowledge) and I set it up with me as admin and her as normal user. Never hear her nag about what the password is and she uses the machine for alot nowadays ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attack vectors:

1. Behind a NAT router (most are nowadays) fat chance of anyone getting in. And ufw running as well: even less chance...  Without a NAT router: it's just software, not hardware.  Software *can* be hacked especially if automatic updates are off.
2. Physical access: Indeed, you're right. the password is the least of your concerns *while the attacker is there*.  **However** if he steals the computer, it is nice to know that *none* of your data can be seen by the thief. (encrypted home directory minimum, or better: full truecrypt). These people don't have technical skills and an encrypted computer is worth less on the black market.
3. LAN: Well, if you're not going to enter any password on the PC why protect the WiFi then?  Open it all up!  >:) Put the router in the corridor so people can plug in their LAN cables while you're at it!  ;)  :D
4. "Easy-to-guess-passwords":

   Definitely avoid [Your country's top 100 passwords](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)

   I told my mother to use the name of the street she lived in as a child (*not really* but something as easy for her to remember) and then add 4 exclamation marks...  She actually *likes* typing her password.  :-)
5. To know how security-conscious people are, ask them the following two questions:

   A. Do you close your front door with a key?

   B. Do you close your curtains?

   If the answer to both questions is "No", then *don't give them any password*, but if one of the questions is answered by "yes", *help them protect themselves by giving them a long password!*  (Remember: in cracking, length is important, not complexity!)

Comment: I do close my curtains every time I have some intimate situations. I live on the tenth floor without any tall buildings around and I do value what birds think of me!

Comment: :-) I wasn't talking about *you*... *I was talking about your converts to Linux!* ;-)  And even if you don't accept my answer as the correct one, an upvote would be nice!  :) I personally don't care about open curtains, nor the lights on, but both at the same time seems to bother my girlfriend...

Answer (score 3):

Not a lot. A threat might be a malicious website that installs software on your system that includes something that probes for your sudo password and sends it out to the world. But modern browser will prompt you if something tries to install software. And the average Linux user tends to be more informed than the average Windows users. Plus there is also the idea that we should know where to go and where not to go. In general Linux users do not download from random websites. We use the repositories and can assume these are safe.

Addition: if you want to convert users to Linux there is one thing you should teach these users. Force them to use the Ubuntu software center and warn them not to search for installation files on the web. The biggest reason for virusses on windows is the fact of visiting nasty websites and downloading malicious installation files. Using Ubuntu software center will reduce that risk a lot.

Just an idea: the one big threat we have is when someone manages to install corrupted software into the Ubuntu repositories. If someone gets something malicous accepted into the repositories like an altered chrome or firefox we are all screwed. Is that likely to happen? Naaa.

Even running local services would not matter. A local webserver with no outside connection enabled (ie. running on localhost) will be safe. Only if you run it not local you will be taking a risk: the scripts created to run your website might be flawed. But I would not call that a home computer anymore.

Your 1st and best safeguard on a home system is your router.

And if you are scared it is always the better option to make regular backups where you detach that harddisk from your system when not making backups.

If an attacker has physical access you are in trouble on a normal system. 1 reboot into a live dvd and your sudo password can be changed. Encrypting the disk would be an option. But that will not prevent a formatting.

Comment: If a malicious code tries asking user for sudo password, user will either fall or not fall for it. Password strength has hardly any significance. Same for all other cases presented.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino true but a short pwd will quickly fall for a brute force attack (where the user is not asked for a pwd). I assumed an installation of software in /home/$USER/

Comment: @user68186 ok agreed on that. Their risk is a bit higher if they try to put windows logic into a linux system. But most of those risks are solved by sticking to USC.

Comment: By the way, about physical presence: not at all. I have a long-standing bet with colleagues at work. Whoever manages to open my PC without my presence wins. They had it in full physical access for weeks, but without result. I just had fully encrypted HDD and a bootloader with keys to it on USB stick that I carry off.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino formatting your disk was out of the order? That would have killed your data ;)

Comment: A short pwd will quickly fall for a brute force attack. Totally agree. My question is - **how and for what reason a bruteforce attack can happen on home PC?** Malicious mail attachment, to perform this, would already need all the access rights it needs to do it's black task - screw user files, steal web passwords, so on. You don't need root for any of this.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino oh I totally agree with you on this ;) And a brute force attack normally happens to a specific computer when someone is pissed off with that person. It will be a -targeted- attack and not a random one.